# IIS server and clinet

Tags: windows, iis

I'm learning windows server 2012r2, I made the server as domain controller with the domain name lab1.com.
ip address of the domain is 192.168.1.1 .
In the dc I installed a IIS role and created a website. the bindings are like this
http    ip: 192.168.1.1    port:8080 name : friends.com
now i created a client and added to the domain. 
when im trying to access the website from client im unable to reach the site. 
Im able to ping the server and i used the command nslookup if there is any wrong with dns but i got the reply from dns. i used telnet command but no use with it also.
please support me for the above.

Comment: Installing IIS on DC is a bad idea in all possible ways. Use another machine instead and that saves you tons of hours to fight.

Comment: Thank you SIr. Is it possible to you to explain why?  Because Im preparing for Interviews.

Comment: Are you registring a cname whose FQDN is displayed as friends.com? Please ensure the domain name is mappping to 192.168.1.1 correctly and you have flush the dns cache. Secondly, please ensure your have created windows firewall inbound rule for 8080 port. Set IIS on DC may not be the problem.

Comment: Besides, could you find the request in your IIS log? If there is no log entry in IIS log. Could you find that failed request in  C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR?

Comment: First try connecting from the server using localhost... if this succeeds, it is likely a firewall issue.